# Как избежать постоянного освобождение памяти мусорщиком?

Tags: java, android, memory, сборщик-мусора

Моя программа считывает данные из устройства и по мере накопления передаёт их парсеру. Считывание ведётся в потоке в бесконечном цикле в `ByteBuffer` средствами `read(ByteBuffer.array(),....)`

Далее этот буфер передаётся в функцию парсера, котрая ожидает `byte[] buffer`. Ну и я делаю `foo(ByteBuffer.array())`. Насколько я понял, Java в этом случае создаёт копию буфера и передёт её в функцию. Ну и так как это вызывается десяток раз в секунду, происходит накопление буферов в памяти и как следствие приход мусорщика. Понятно что это расточительство ресурсов. 
Как быть? Как я должен передать массив байт конкретной длины в функцию так, чтобы оно не скопировалось? Понятие указателей есть в java?

Answer (score 2):

Метод `ByteBuffer.array()` не создает копию массива, а возвращает реальный массив, который используется реализацией буфера.

Скорее всего память постоянно выделяет сам парсер.

Comment: Вы наверное меня не так поняли. Дело не в методе а в Java. Если верить офицальной документации от Oracle, то Java использует метод  **Pass-by-value**.<br/> **Pass-by-value**
`The actual parameter (or argument expression) is fully evaluated and the resulting value is copied into a location being used to hold the formal parameter's value during method/function execution. That location is typically a chunk of memory on the runtime stack for the application (which is how Java handles it), but other languages could choose parameter storage differently.`

Comment: Другими словами Ява всегда копирует оригинал при передаче его в функцию и работает в функции с копией. Вот и получается, я передаю byte[] array, а получаю копию в памяти, которую потом мусорщик подбирает.

Comment: Нет, аллокация происходит лишь при конструировании нового массива через new, вы можете убедится в этом при помощи профилировщика, например

Comment: Но факт остаётся фактом, на профиле памяти конкретная пила. Постоянные вызовы мусорщика. Да и интернет утверждает об обратном. Нет повода не верить Ораклу.  Нашёл вот такое дело [ссылка](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html), вроде как объекты передаются указателями, byte[n] вроде объект, но по факту копируется. Попробую переписать функцию так, чтобы передавался ByteBuffer....

Comment: А вы еще не посмотрели что GC кушает то? Ссылка которую вы привели 15 летней давности

Comment: А как посмотреть что именно сделал GC? Я с явой не дружу.  Ссылка то да, но ничего не поменялось в описании явы. Это же самое но другими словами в офицальной документации до сих пор.

Comment: @Spider Вы неверно понимаете механизм передачи значений в Java. В данном случае по значению передаются ссылка на массив, а не копия массива.

Пила на профиле сборки - это нормально. Хуже, когда у вас прямая под максимумом :)

Берите профайлер и смотрите, что занимает память. СКорее всего это результат работы вашего парсера или другой части вашего кода.

Comment: А вот и нет. Переписал парсер на передачу в него ByteBuffer, а не byte[] и всё стало на свои места. GC перестал флудить о отчистите памяти и график памяти стал ровным.

Comment: @Spider Не верю. Код до и код после в студию!

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз когда вы вызываете byteBuffer.array() возвращается ссылка на один и тот же массив. Вы можете увидеть это просто заглянув в реализацию.

Comment: см. комментарий выше.